# Appying our own action to Facebook Login button & closing all Facebook screens. 

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using fbconnect api in my project. When the login dialog gets opened where we entered our credentials, when we click on login button then it is redirected to the publish page how can we close the login page or post to wall page or view.
My problem is I don't want to open any page belongs to face book API, instead i want to open my own page. Any one can help or suggest. [image: This is my login page]

Comment: kindly post your Publish Page Screenshot !

Comment: Kalyan Andra if you are satisfied then accept answers.

Comment: my suggestion is use GraphAPI ........

Answer (score 0):

You can open your own view depending upon your requirement. After successful Login following delegate method is called

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid 
{
    self.usession=session;
    [self postToWall];

}
```

Here  i am calling my own custom method postToWall. Where i create publish dialog as below:

```
-(void)postToWall
{
    FBStreamDialog *dialog=[[[FBStreamDialog alloc]init]autorelease];
    dialog.userMessagePrompt=@"Enter Message to Post";
    [dialog show];
}
```

You can create your own view in `postToWall` in place of `FBStreamDialog` OR if you want to load request of another page then load that URL in Web View of FBStreamDialog.m class.

Comment: Actually i want to close the login  or Facebook screen after successful login. and to go or open another view which is my own.

Comment: @KalyanAndra then simply create your view in 
-(void)postToWall
{
   // create your own view
}

Comment: Thanks Amit but i want to close all Facebook screens from background also

Comment: Hi Dear @KalyanAndra try it and you will see that after successful lo-gin  the login screen automatically will disapear,there is no need to any other logic. First try it and then tell me. Best of luck !!

Comment: what is your exact problem please share completely and then if you have any problem then you are most welcome.

Comment: actually in my app am using facebook api in that first it will show login screen after entering the credentials, pressing login button it is showing post to wall view with share and cancel button and one text field , but i dont want that post to wall screen i want to close all the facebook screens and move to my own view/screen

Comment: Ok as i mentioned above use this delegate method - (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid. and create your own view in this delegate method where i am calling [self postToWall];

Answer (score 0):

In `FBConnect` there is a class `FBDialog` which is using `UIWebView` for `Facebook` login authentication. The `FBDialog` class implements the `UIWebView delegate protocol`. So if you want to perform your action on login button press then you can handle it in `FBDialog.m` in `UIWebView` delegate -

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

which will call when you press on `login` button.

Comment: Actually i want to close the login or Facebook screen after successful login. and to go or open another view which is my own. and how can we handle this method                                  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Comment: @KalyanAndra can you please tell me how are you opening this facebook credential page ?

Comment: Thanks Saadnib, By calling some methods in FBConnect folder finally - (void)show{} in FBDialog and when i click login button - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType also called

Comment: @KalyanAndra from your previous comment i got that you want to login in facebook but don't want to publish on facebook but want to open your own page after login successfully. If i am right then you need to call fbPremission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil];
   
   [facebook authorize:fbPremission delegate:self]; and when you call the above then FBSessionDelegate call this function - (void)fbDidLogin here you can do your work.

Comment: How Can we call this fbPremission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil]; [facebook authorize:fbPremission delegate:self];     and I did'nt found - (void)fbDidLogin method

Comment: @KalyanAndra you can a look at this repo, it will show you how to implement fbconnect, it will help you a lot.

Comment: can i know what is repo or it is report

Comment: @KalyanAndra sorry i forgot to add the link here is the link for repo - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/2276606a69b7f706b71860a9821c7384934c7629/sample/Hackbook